# Shortening of code, ORDER BY and SWITCH

Tags: php, mysql

Can you help me with shortening of code. Point is, that I want to fetch data from database in different order depening on given `$T`. Any idea?

```
public function rewriteQuery($T){

switch ($T) {

    case 0:
        $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,2,3,4,5,6)";  
        break;
     case 1:
        $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,2,3,4,5,6,1)";  
        break;
     case 2:
        $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,4,5,6,1,2)";    
        break;
     case 3:
       $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,4,5,6,1,2,3)";  
        break;
     case 4:
      $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,6,1,2,3,4)";  
        break;
    default:
       $query="SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,6,1,2,3,4,5)";  
    break;

    }        

  return $query;             

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to shorten this would be to create an array that returns the fields for the `order by`.

Something like this:

```
$order_by_array = array(
  0 => "(id,1,2,3,4,5,6)", 
  1 => "(id,2,3,4,5,6,1)", 
  2 => "(id,3,4,5,6,1,2)", 
  3 => "(id,4,5,6,1,2,3)", 
  4 => "(id,5,6,1,2,3,4)"
);
```

Then your `rewriteQuery($T)` function can be re-written as:

```
public function rewriteQuery($T){
  $order_by = "(id,6,1,2,3,4,5)"; // Default
  if (array_key_exists($T, $order_by_array)) {
    $order_by = $order_by_array[$T];
  }

  $query = "SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD{$order_by}";
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Oops, thanks for catching that.  Mixture of type copy/paste...:)

Answer (score 0):

Otherthan removing the redundancy in constructing the query string, I don't see much more that could be shorten:

```
public function rewriteQuery($T){

$query = "SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD";
switch ($T) {
    case 0:
        $query.="(id,1,2,3,4,5,6)";  
        break;
     case 1:
        $query.="(id,2,3,4,5,6,1)";  
        break;
     case 2:
        $query.="(id,3,4,5,6,1,2)";    
        break;
     case 3:
       $query.="(id,4,5,6,1,2,3)";  
        break;
     case 4:
      $query.="(id,5,6,1,2,3,4)";  
        break;
    default:
       $query.="(id,6,1,2,3,4,5)";  
    break;

    }        

  return $query;
```

Comment: string concatenation in PHP is done with the `.` operator, not `+`.

Comment: `$query.="(id,1,2,3,4,5,6)";` and not `$query+="(id,1,2,3,4,5,6)";` etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Plus this => `$query = =` should be `$query =` you have 2x `==`

Comment: thanks, made the corrections. Guess I should finish my first morning coffee first - lol.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure, just make sure you keep it away from your keyboard ;-) I did that "once" lol The operative word here is `once`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd prefer the other answers in case your ordering is fixed, here's a more flexible solution:

```
function rewriteQuery($T) {
    $query = "SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,";
    $order = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

    if($T < count($order)) {
        for($i = $T, $end = false;;$i++) {
            if($i == count($order)) {
                $i = 0;
                $end = true;
            }

            if($end && $i == $T) {
                break;
            }

            $query .= $order[$i] . ",";
        }

        $query = substr($query, 0, -1) . ")";

        return $query;
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

$index = 5;

echo rewriteQuery($index);
```

See the [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4k1-gdi).

Basically you have to realise that your `$T` is nothing else than the index from where you wanna start your order (given your order as an array). Once you realised this you may implement the logic:
with `$T` as our start we walk through the array until we reach the end, then set `$i` to zero and active an ending-condition to not run an infinite loop. `$i` will continue to increase again until it reaches `$T` and then drop out of the loop. All that is left is getting rid of the trailing `,`. I just replace it with a `)` to complete the query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wanted to be particularly horrible, you could calculate the whole thing:

```
public function rewriteQuery($T){
  $num_cols = 6;
  // Build a naughty little array to pick numbers from.
  $numbers = array_merge(range(1, $num_cols, 1), range(1, $num_cols, 1));
  // Pick the section from the array corresponding to our $T
  $rotated = array_slice($numbers, $T, $num_cols);
  // Shove "id" on the front
  array_unshift($rotated, 'id');
  // Build a string
  $final_list = implode(", ", $rotated);
  // Build the SQL
  $query = "SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY FIELD($final_list)";
  return $query;
}
```

But frankly, I honestly don't think there's that much wrong with what you're doing. Separating out the ordering string from the main query, as suggested by other answers, will prevent you having to change a ton of lines if your main query changes, which is good.

The idea is to find a happy balance between copy-and-paste code, which is hard to maintain, and code that's so clever you won't understand it when you go back to it in three week's time. And I'd always err on the side of the former.

By which I mean: don't take this answer seriously -- it's just an example of how far you can go wrong in terms of readability and maintainability if you go a little too far down the road of "I must never even vaguely repeat myself."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know you wanted the code to be short, but just in case there's a call for large number of switches, you can try a loop rather than manual arrays as your order has a good pattern.

```
public function rewriteQuery($T)
{
    $query = "SELECT id, title FROM kshome WHERE del=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY FIELD";
    $fieldOrder =" (id, ";

    $j = $T;
    $i=1;

    if($j > 0 && $j < 5)    // or whatever you wish
    {   
        while(1)
        {   // replace 6 (below) by whatever your limit is
            $fieldOrder .= ($j % 6) + 1;

            if($i < 6)
                $fieldOrder .= ", ";
            else
                break;

            $j++; $i++;
        }

    }
    else
    {   $fieldOrder .= "6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"; 
        // or maybe a loop again! :-D
    }
    $fieldOrder .= " )";
    return($query.$fieldOrder);
}
```